# Bring specific Word instance to front VB

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I am using the following Namespace: `Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop`

I need a function, that brings a specific Word-Instance to front.
Optimal solution would be

```
Public Sub toFront(ByVal wdObj as Word.Application, ByVal filePath as String)
     'sends by filePath specified Word-Instance to Front
End Sub
```

I know there is `Word.Application.Activate`, but that does not seem to be working all the time and also it only activates the ActiveDocument.

I already tried the following functions where wdObj is a `Word.Application`

```
 wdObj.Activate()
 wdObj.Application.Documents(My.Settings.DocPath).Activate()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a function in Interop. Try to use WinApi instead:

```
void BringWindowToTop (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc) {

  // To make it active document
  doc.Activate(); 

  // I'm not 100% sure, but I think MainWindowHandle gives
  // a handle of currently active window of word
  IntPtr hwnd = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;

  BringWindowToTop(hwnd);
}
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool BringWindowToTop(IntPtr hWnd);
```